# Month and Week names are lower case

Tags: date, localization

"Dates & Times" for Brazil are lower case while other locations it is title case. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Where should I report this issue?

[image: "Dates & Times" for United States]
[image: "Dates & Times" for and Brazil]

I still don't have an answer.

Many languages have Month/Week names with Title case. 
It happens that for Portuguese (Brazil) Pt-Br they are in a lower case like shown in the image below.

**Do you know where I can place a bug report about that?**

[image]

Comment: I can't see any issue. Are you saying month and week days names should be capitalized in portuguese? We should capitalize such names [**in english**](https://www.englishgrammar.org/spelling-capital-letters/), but not [**in portuguese**](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono24.php).

Comment: I'm saying they should be capitalized to match the OS. It is a matter of style. Every window name has a Title case, every entry on a menu is also a Title case, we are just using the lowercase month/week names because the grammar says that they are not like person names anymore. But suppose you are going to write a sentence that starts with the month name. For example: "Janeiro é o primeiro mes do ano." In this case, the word janeiro start with uppercase J, right? So. That is my point. In the image I presented you, it is better to keep it Title case because it will match better with the OS.